# Change SOAP produced by WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

Please tell me how to change a little SOAP.

Here's what happens:

```
<s: Envelope>
<s: Header>
...
</s: Header>
<s: Body>
<Method1 xmlns="http://my.site">                  
  <Param1 xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
...
```

MyTestMethod - is the name of the method of service. In the  **must be** param1. Without Method1's level at all.

Here the contract:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://my.site")]
public interface IMyService
{
[OperationContract]
Method1Response Method1(Method1Request param1);
}
```

I need to get

```
<s: Envelope>
<s: Header>
...
</s: Header>
<s: Body>
  <Param1 xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Value1>...
    <Value2>...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to use MessageContract
But. From trying to solve a problem with it - collided with another:
[Incorrect Soap's namespaces in inner complex types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543732/incorrect-soaps-namespaces-in-inner-complex-types)

That is interesting. The problem that I encountered, there is in most articles describing MessageContract!
In all of them, which uses a nested complex type, everywhere manifested this artifact! Just a look any, and notice it.But, for the purposes of article this artifact does not matter. Therefore, it is no one pays attention.
Unfortunately for me, this bug is critical.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the Interface IClientMessageInspector and derive from it.

```
public class SOAPInspector : IClientMessageInspector {
public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState) {
  //Your code
}

public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel) {
    //Your code
}
}
```

Using the BeforeSendRequest Method you can modify the generated SOAP message before sending.

To get your Inspector running you need in addition an EndpointBehaviour class like:

```
public class SOAPEndpointBehaviour : IEndpointBehavior {

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime) {
      clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new SOAPInspector());
    }
}
```

And finally register your Behaviour

```
yourServiceClient.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new SOAPEndpointBehaviour());
```

Comment: We'll have to parse the entire SOAP request for this?

Comment: @SoaperPlus I'm afraid yes. But .NET offers quite comfortable classes for stuff like that. You could use the request.WriteBody() Method to Wirte it to an XMLDictionaryWriter.
Or simply use ToString() and then XDocument.Parse()